# How to access iPhone's Calendar so I can get the attendees of a meeting

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

How can I access the iPhone's calendar so I can get the attendees of a meeting?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use "EventKit" for that:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide

Answer (score 0):

Use EventKit framework

Have a look at this demo: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleEKDemo/Listings/Classes_RootViewController_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010160-Classes_RootViewController_h-DontLinkElementID_3

Solves your problem.

Code:

```
self.eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
self.eventsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:0];
self.defaultCalendar = [self.eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents];
NSArray *calendarArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:defaultCalendar];
```

Hope this helps to start...